# How to kill/delete stuck icon on dock? (Firefox)

Tags: macos, mac, firefox, osx-yosemite

I'm running multiple Firefoxes by this command:

```
/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin -p -private-window
```

Most of them I quit by `CMD+Q` but some of them are stuck.

```
Running command  ps aux | grep firefox
607   5.8 12.9  4798148 1081464 s008  S    金10AM 760:54.46 /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin -p -private-window -foreground
25308   0.0  0.0  2432772    640 s020  S+    4:24PM   0:00.00 grep firefox
```

As you can see there is only one active Firefox, but I have also 3 that are not active and I can't close/quit them.

[image]

How to kill/delete the stuck icons on dock without restarting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this applies to your situation, but allow me to describe what was happening to me, and how I fixed it:

### Specs

MBP Retina,
OS X 10.11.2 (El Capitan),
Firefox 43.0.4 (although the issue started on the previous update, I believe)

### Problem

Like you, I was experiencing multiple instances of the Firefox icon on the Dock, some time after starting up the program. When I attempted to quit Firefox, it stopped responding. Any attempts to Force Quit the program failed, I could not Restart nor Shut Down the computer via the usual methods, and so I was (in most cases) resorting to a "hard" reboot.

### Troubleshooting

- Started Firefox in "safe" mode, disabled hardware acceleration and all plugins -> problem persisted.
- Firefox "refresh" -> problem persisted.
- Force quit commands via Terminal -> worked, but only for that Firefox instance.

### Solution

Like me, you probably want a long term solution rather than a quick fix. To be honest, it was rather simple, and I have not had an issue since...

1. Navigate to /Applications and move Firefox.app to the Trash. Empty the Trash.
2. Download the Firefox installer: https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/
3. Install Firefox again and you should be good to go.

### Updates

I have had the issue described above a few times now, but it is far less often. I want to say that clicking the Firefox dock icon when Firefox is already open sometimes results in this problem. Not sure though and have not tested this theory. Regardless, as of this writing, it is an "unsquashed" bug.

#### 04/05/16

Version: Firefox 45.0.1

So last night I noticed at least one of the situations that will cause this to happen: Firefox crashed once because of (I assume) scripting errors on a given web page. I opted to report the crash, relaunch Firefox, and restore previous windows. Of course, the same web page loaded again, causing another crash. Again, opted to do report and restore. At this point I had 3 Firefox dock icons: 1 for my actual Firefox symbolic link, and two for the restored sessions, all of them locked.

#### 04/07/16

Version: Firefox 45.0.1

I've confirmed my previous update: in the case that Firefox crashes, select "Quit Firefox" rather than "Restart Firefox" and the issue of multiple, "stuck" instances of Firefox will be avoided.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to hold the ⌥ key while right clicking the firefox icon? then you can "force quit" the application which equals a hard quit.

Comment: Thank you for your post, yup I tried it :) Icons are still there )

Comment: open the "Terminal.app" under Utilities,  type(everything between the hashes): #
 for i in ps -ef | grep -i "firefox.app" | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'`; do kill -9 $i; echo "";done #
**But be aware**, this is a very brutal way to kill a program and all instances of Firefox will be killed

Comment: Sorry, still there :)

Comment: I'm sorry, no idea anymore…